# How to secure a token link?

Tags: c#

I have set up a reset password token, as usual user can click a forgot password link and we send them a token link to reset their password, I want the token will be expired in 15 minutes and it can be used only once and forwarded email token can not be be used.

how to do this in ASP NEt Core?

```
     services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName(Security.Application_Name)
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Security.Key_Ring_Path));

        services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
        options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
```

Comment: `forwarded email token can not be be used` How do you plan to detect this?

Comment: currently still investigating Antifrogery but still no luck

Comment: I mean - it literally isn't possible to reliably detect that the token email was forwarded to someone else. There is no way to _reliably_ detect that someone forwarded the email to someone else. And even if you could it wouldn't be helpful, since they may have been forwarding the email to _themselves_ which is 100% legitimate.

Comment: You can generate random token (with RNGCryptoServiceProvider) and put it into database with timestamp. When user go to "yourhost/auth/resetPass?token=...." you will be able to check if that token exists in db and how long ago it was generated. But as mjwills already said there is no reliable way to protect against forwarding. Also I do not see any point in this protection. If someone can access my email inbox he/she already able to steal my account without forwarding that token